# Как передать свои данные в очередь Queue Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, очередь-задач

Как мне передать свои данные в очередь Queue что бы при обработке очереди в методе handle() - производились операции над ними?
Пробую кидать как в примере но данные мои только из последней очереди показывает, тоесть если элемент в очереди 1 то все хорошо, но если больше то только последний $my_data выводится.

```
class SendReminderEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

protected $my_data;

public function __construct($my_data)
{
  $this->my_data = $my_data;
}

public function handle()
{
  echo $my_data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На примере отправки письма, в контролере:

```
        $data['template'] = 'emails.message';  
        $data['to'] = config('mail.notification.address');
        $data['subject'] = $request->input('topic');
        $data['email'] = $request->input('email');
        $data['topic'] = $request->input('topic');
        $data['body'] = $request->input('body');
        $job = (new SendEmailJob($data))->onQueue('email');

        dispatch($job);
```

В задаче

```
class SendEmailJob extends Job
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data;

    /**
     * SendEmailJob constructor.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $data = $this->data;
        $body = view($data['template'], $data)->render();

        try{
            $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(config('mail.host'), config('mail.port'), config('mail.encryption'))
                ->setUsername(config('mail.username'))
                ->setPassword(config('mail.password'));
            $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance($data['subject'])
                ->setFrom([config('mail.from.address') => config('mail.from.name')])
                ->setTo([$data['to']])
                ->setBody($body,'text/html');

            return $mailer->send($message);

        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Делаю так же само как и у вас, в БД смотрю есть моя строка в задаче но почемуто не обрабатывается она вот код задачи моей `class CheckWPPermissionQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(){

        $data = $this->data;

            echo $data;


    }
}`

Comment: Вот мой контроллер ->https://pastebin.com/ZcYakJXc а вот контороллер задач ->https://pastebin.com/8hQzb7zk . Когда я запускаю команду "php artisan queue:work" работает , но чтото делается не так потому что  "echo $data;" из метода handle() не выводит ничего или же выводит последнюю мою строку, в таблице jobs в БД есть во всех задачах мои данные. Вот скриин на котором видно из терминала как выполняются моя очередь-> http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/04/15/0020/2648/1354328/28/c1c79b2ffb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Все решил! оказывается нужно было в контроллере в строке

```
$urls = explode("\n", $request->input('addurls'))
```

добавить `\r` что-бы получилось вот так

```
$urls = explode("\r\n", $request->input('addurls'))
```